# How to know m2 repository generated maven version

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

Recently I have upgraded maven from 2.x to 3.x and then deleted the total .m2 repository from Users and again generated .m2,

Everything looks good but I want get the confirmation from repository should these all are generated using maven 3.x.

Can some one help me out?

Comment: What exactly should be generated? (How did you do the generation?)

Comment: I done with mvn install   from project main pom xml , when I check .m2 it will have all dependencies and my app folders, I want get the confirmation like these are generated using maven 3

Comment: What kind of confirmation? And if there would be something like this? What is the result of that? What kind of question will it answer?

Comment: how to know generated war file is from maven 3?

Comment: The contents of a repository (locally your .m2) is **not** dependent on the version of Maven.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure that the dependencies are downloaded through your new maven version. You can add a dependency, which does not exist in your local repository, through your new project, which uses maven 3 and you run the `mvn clean install` command in the path, in where you parent pom is and then, you can check whether this new dependency in your local repository or not. However, as SiKing said, the content is independent from the version of the maven. You can make a small test like i described.